# Creating array of structure from matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array of structure similar to this:

```
AAA(1).Size = rand(1,10);
AAA(2).Size = rand(1,10);
AAA(...).Size = rand(1,10);
...
```

I have a matrix such as this:

```
mMatrix = [rand(1,100); rand(1,100); ...]
```

How can I assign the row values of `mMatrix` to a new structure in `AAA` (here called `NumberOfElement`), in a single call, without having to use a loop?

```
nRow = size(mMatrix, 1);
for ii = 1:nRow
    AAA(ii).NumberOfElement = mMatrix(ii,:);
end
```

Also, could this be done for multiple matrices and multiple new structures in `AAA`, such as:

```
nRow = size(mMatrixDataset1, 1); % The matrices have the same number of rows
for ii = 1:nRow
    AAA(ii).NumberOfElementDataset1 = mMatrixDataset1(ii,:);
    AAA(ii).NumberOfElementDataset2 = mMatrixDataset2(ii,:);
    AAA(ii).NumberOfElementDataset3 = mMatrixDataset3(ii,:);
    ...
end
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: there may be a reason to avoid the loop, but if you just want code that is easy to understand and performs quite efficiently, you should seriously consider a loop for this kind of assignment to a struct.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split up the matrix `mMatrix` into multiple cells where each cell would be a row of your matrix.  We can do this with [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and then assign to each element in your structure with a single unfolding call.  This will work regardless of whether the structure has been declared previously or not. Therefore:

```
c = mat2cell(mMatrix, ones(size(mMatrix,1),1), size(mMatrix, 2));
[AAA(1:size(mMatrix,1)).NumberOfElement] = c{:};
```

---

## Example use

```
%// Set up code
mMatrix = rand(4, 100);

%// Code I wrote above
c = mat2cell(mMatrix, ones(size(mMatrix,1),1), size(mMatrix, 2));
[AAA(1:size(mMatrix,1)).NumberOfElement] = c{:};

AAA = 

1x4 struct array with fields:

    NumberOfElement
```

We can go through each structure with a `for` loop to show what each `NumberOfElement` field looks like:

```
for ii = 1 : size(mMatrix, 1)
    disp(['Structure ' num2str(ii)]);
    disp(['Row ' num2str(ii) ' of matrix']);
    disp(mMatrix(ii,:));
    disp('Structure contents')
    disp(AAA(ii).NumberOfElement);
end
```

The above code shows you each row of the matrix stored in `mMatrix` and what the actual field is for each element in your structure.

I get:

```
Structure 1
Row 1 of matrix
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.4229    0.6959    0.0688    0.4076    0.5313    0.7788    0.1537    0.4574
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.6377    0.2891    0.2548    0.3445    0.6022    0.4624    0.3225    0.1759
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.3411    0.2428    0.1887    0.6834    0.6476    0.2089    0.6073    0.7703
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.8419    0.5822    0.3181    0.4795    0.5439    0.2187    0.4046    0.6279
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.1920    0.5254    0.3935    0.3477    0.0445    0.6878    0.6834    0.3309
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.8217    0.7691    0.3774    0.3276    0.7689    0.5144    0.1999    0.7900
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.1117    0.1897    0.8507    0.5828    0.0005    0.5277    0.4981    0.7386
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.0835    0.8908    0.9283    0.8627    0.5523    0.3624    0.1231    0.0427
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.6952    0.1239    0.2703    0.4170    0.1057    0.5737    0.7378    0.9844
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.1776    0.9391    0.4671    0.5590    0.0542    0.8985    0.7069    0.4648
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.1781    0.3358    0.6754    0.7455    0.5972    0.8949    0.4417    0.0934
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.9954    0.2982    0.6311    0.9051    0.3381    0.0484    0.7297    0.6925
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.7802    0.1048    0.8905    0.0729
Structure contents
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.4229    0.6959    0.0688    0.4076    0.5313    0.7788    0.1537    0.4574
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.6377    0.2891    0.2548    0.3445    0.6022    0.4624    0.3225    0.1759
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.3411    0.2428    0.1887    0.6834    0.6476    0.2089    0.6073    0.7703
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.8419    0.5822    0.3181    0.4795    0.5439    0.2187    0.4046    0.6279
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.1920    0.5254    0.3935    0.3477    0.0445    0.6878    0.6834    0.3309
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.8217    0.7691    0.3774    0.3276    0.7689    0.5144    0.1999    0.7900
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.1117    0.1897    0.8507    0.5828    0.0005    0.5277    0.4981    0.7386
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.0835    0.8908    0.9283    0.8627    0.5523    0.3624    0.1231    0.0427
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.6952    0.1239    0.2703    0.4170    0.1057    0.5737    0.7378    0.9844
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.1776    0.9391    0.4671    0.5590    0.0542    0.8985    0.7069    0.4648
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.1781    0.3358    0.6754    0.7455    0.5972    0.8949    0.4417    0.0934
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.9954    0.2982    0.6311    0.9051    0.3381    0.0484    0.7297    0.6925
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.7802    0.1048    0.8905    0.0729
Structure 2
Row 2 of matrix
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.0942    0.6999    0.3196    0.8200    0.3251    0.4235    0.2810    0.8754
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.9577    0.6718    0.2240    0.7805    0.3868    0.4243    0.7847    0.7218
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.6074    0.9174    0.2875    0.5466    0.6790    0.7093    0.4501    0.3502
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.8329    0.5407    0.1192    0.6393    0.7210    0.1058    0.4484    0.7720
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.1389    0.5303    0.6714    0.1500    0.7549    0.3592    0.7040    0.4243
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.4299    0.3968    0.2160    0.6713    0.1673    0.8843    0.4070    0.3185
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.1363    0.4950    0.5606    0.8154    0.8654    0.4795    0.9009    0.5860
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.6260    0.9823    0.5801    0.4843    0.6299    0.0495    0.2055    0.6352
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.4991    0.4904    0.2085    0.2060    0.1420    0.0521    0.0634    0.8589
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.3986    0.3013    0.6482    0.8541    0.1771    0.1182    0.9995    0.7640
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.3596    0.1757    0.4685    0.7363    0.2999    0.0715    0.0133    0.3074
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.3321    0.0464    0.0899    0.5338    0.2940    0.6679    0.7073    0.5567
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.3376    0.1279    0.7990    0.0885
Structure contents
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.0942    0.6999    0.3196    0.8200    0.3251    0.4235    0.2810    0.8754
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.9577    0.6718    0.2240    0.7805    0.3868    0.4243    0.7847    0.7218
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.6074    0.9174    0.2875    0.5466    0.6790    0.7093    0.4501    0.3502
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.8329    0.5407    0.1192    0.6393    0.7210    0.1058    0.4484    0.7720
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.1389    0.5303    0.6714    0.1500    0.7549    0.3592    0.7040    0.4243
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.4299    0.3968    0.2160    0.6713    0.1673    0.8843    0.4070    0.3185
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.1363    0.4950    0.5606    0.8154    0.8654    0.4795    0.9009    0.5860
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.6260    0.9823    0.5801    0.4843    0.6299    0.0495    0.2055    0.6352
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.4991    0.4904    0.2085    0.2060    0.1420    0.0521    0.0634    0.8589
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.3986    0.3013    0.6482    0.8541    0.1771    0.1182    0.9995    0.7640
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.3596    0.1757    0.4685    0.7363    0.2999    0.0715    0.0133    0.3074
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.3321    0.0464    0.0899    0.5338    0.2940    0.6679    0.7073    0.5567
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.3376    0.1279    0.7990    0.0885
Structure 3
Row 3 of matrix
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.5985    0.6385    0.5309    0.7184    0.1056    0.0908    0.4401    0.5181
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.2407    0.6951    0.6678    0.6753    0.9160    0.4609    0.4714    0.4735
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.1917    0.2691    0.0911    0.4257    0.6358    0.2362    0.4587    0.6620
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.2564    0.8699    0.9398    0.5447    0.5225    0.1097    0.3658    0.9329
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.6963    0.8611    0.7413    0.5861    0.2428    0.7363    0.4423    0.2703
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.8878    0.8085    0.7904    0.4386    0.8620    0.5880    0.7487    0.5341
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.6787    0.1476    0.9296    0.8790    0.6126    0.8013    0.5747    0.2467
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.6609    0.7690    0.0170    0.8449    0.0320    0.4896    0.1465    0.2819
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.5358    0.8530    0.5650    0.9479    0.1665    0.9312    0.8604    0.7856
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.1339    0.2955    0.0252    0.3479    0.6628    0.9884    0.2878    0.8182
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.0567    0.2089    0.9121    0.5619    0.1341    0.2425    0.8972    0.4561
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.2973    0.5054    0.0809    0.1092    0.7463    0.6035    0.7814    0.3965
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.6079    0.5495    0.7343    0.7984
Structure contents
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.5985    0.6385    0.5309    0.7184    0.1056    0.0908    0.4401    0.5181
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.2407    0.6951    0.6678    0.6753    0.9160    0.4609    0.4714    0.4735
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.1917    0.2691    0.0911    0.4257    0.6358    0.2362    0.4587    0.6620
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.2564    0.8699    0.9398    0.5447    0.5225    0.1097    0.3658    0.9329
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.6963    0.8611    0.7413    0.5861    0.2428    0.7363    0.4423    0.2703
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.8878    0.8085    0.7904    0.4386    0.8620    0.5880    0.7487    0.5341
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.6787    0.1476    0.9296    0.8790    0.6126    0.8013    0.5747    0.2467
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.6609    0.7690    0.0170    0.8449    0.0320    0.4896    0.1465    0.2819
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.5358    0.8530    0.5650    0.9479    0.1665    0.9312    0.8604    0.7856
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.1339    0.2955    0.0252    0.3479    0.6628    0.9884    0.2878    0.8182
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.0567    0.2089    0.9121    0.5619    0.1341    0.2425    0.8972    0.4561
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.2973    0.5054    0.0809    0.1092    0.7463    0.6035    0.7814    0.3965
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.6079    0.5495    0.7343    0.7984
Structure 4
Row 4 of matrix
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.4709    0.0336    0.6544    0.9686    0.6110    0.2665    0.5271    0.9436
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.6761    0.0680    0.8444    0.0067    0.0012    0.7702    0.0358    0.1527
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.7384    0.7655    0.5762    0.6444    0.9452    0.1194    0.6619    0.4162
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.6135    0.2648    0.6456    0.6473    0.9937    0.0636    0.7635    0.9727
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.0938    0.4849    0.5201    0.2621    0.4424    0.3947    0.0196    0.1971
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.3912    0.7551    0.9493    0.8335    0.9899    0.1548    0.8256    0.0900
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.4952    0.0550    0.6967    0.9889    0.9900    0.2278    0.8452    0.6664
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.7298    0.5814    0.1209    0.2094    0.6147    0.1925    0.1891    0.5386
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.4452    0.8739    0.6403    0.0821    0.6210    0.7287    0.9344    0.5134
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.0309    0.3329    0.8422    0.4460    0.3308    0.5400    0.4145    0.1002
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.5219    0.9052    0.1040    0.1842    0.2126    0.0538    0.1967    0.1017
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.0620    0.7614    0.7772    0.8258    0.0103    0.5261    0.2880    0.0616
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.7413    0.4852    0.0513    0.9430
Structure contents
  Columns 1 through 8
    0.4709    0.0336    0.6544    0.9686    0.6110    0.2665    0.5271    0.9436
  Columns 9 through 16
    0.6761    0.0680    0.8444    0.0067    0.0012    0.7702    0.0358    0.1527
  Columns 17 through 24
    0.7384    0.7655    0.5762    0.6444    0.9452    0.1194    0.6619    0.4162
  Columns 25 through 32
    0.6135    0.2648    0.6456    0.6473    0.9937    0.0636    0.7635    0.9727
  Columns 33 through 40
    0.0938    0.4849    0.5201    0.2621    0.4424    0.3947    0.0196    0.1971
  Columns 41 through 48
    0.3912    0.7551    0.9493    0.8335    0.9899    0.1548    0.8256    0.0900
  Columns 49 through 56
    0.4952    0.0550    0.6967    0.9889    0.9900    0.2278    0.8452    0.6664
  Columns 57 through 64
    0.7298    0.5814    0.1209    0.2094    0.6147    0.1925    0.1891    0.5386
  Columns 65 through 72
    0.4452    0.8739    0.6403    0.0821    0.6210    0.7287    0.9344    0.5134
  Columns 73 through 80
    0.0309    0.3329    0.8422    0.4460    0.3308    0.5400    0.4145    0.1002
  Columns 81 through 88
    0.5219    0.9052    0.1040    0.1842    0.2126    0.0538    0.1967    0.1017
  Columns 89 through 96
    0.0620    0.7614    0.7772    0.8258    0.0103    0.5261    0.2880    0.0616
  Columns 97 through 100
    0.7413    0.4852    0.0513    0.9430
```

Comment: By using your example, I only get 1 field. I can't access AAA(2).NumberOfElement.

Comment: @m_power - At the beginning I said **assuming your structure has already been defined**, so you'll need to do what I did in the example.  As such, make an empty structure, then use `repmat` to replicate for as many rows in your matrix you want, and then run the code.

Comment: @m_power - I've edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: I copied and executed your code (i.e. Example Use), which initialize AAA. I replaced `[AAA.NumberOfElement] = c{:}` with `[AAA(1:4).NumberOfElement] = c{:}` and now it works. But I don't see how you are getting 4x1 struct array with fields NumberOfElement with your posted example.

Comment: @m_power - Yup I see it now.  Good catch.

Comment: Also, I'm getting this warning when running your example : `Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2 Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure
Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. `

Comment: @m_power - Yeah I don't get that warning so I had to manually assign to the structure when unrolling to make it compatible.  I've updated my answer.  I also don't have to declare the structure first.  Thanks!

Comment: It works as expected now. Is converting the matrix to a cell array the only way?

Comment: @m_power - That's the only way I can see in order to take advantage of the unrolling.  The `{:}` for cells essentially will unpack each cell element so you can place each cell into a corresponding variable... in our case, it's a field for each element in a structure.  If you kept it as an array, there's no way to tell MATLAB how to unpack the rows into the corresponding fields.  Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted as it clearly answers the question, but honestly I think that using a loop would be better than this approach.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - I agree.  The `for` loop is much more intuitive and it clearly shows you what you're doing.  Thank you for the +1 though!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, In my example I'm only assigning the matrix to a single new structure. However, in my script the loop is doing the same thing for multiple variables and multiple matrices, hence why I'm trying to simplify and remove the loop.

Comment: @LuisMendo - If we are creating a new structure from the beginning, then that will certainly work.  However, if we want to append to an existing structure, then my code should work! BTW, thanks for the +1!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for the general case of `multiple matrices and multiple new structures` using [`cell2struct`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) -

```
num_matrices = 3; %// Number of matrices to be used
fnames = {'set1','set2','set3'} %// Fieldnames for each matrix
M = cat(1,mat1,mat2,mat3) %// Concatenate all matrices into a single one

%// Form cell array version of the concatenated array and then the struct
C = reshape(mat2cell(M,ones(1,size(M,1)),size(M,2)),size(mat1,1),[])

%// Finally create the struct 
AAA = cell2struct(C,fnames,2)
```

---

Sample inputs and outputs -

```
>> mat1
mat1 =
    0.2232    0.9404    0.3981    0.6934    0.5052    0.6516    0.1042
    0.5832    0.8867    0.2036    0.5595    0.2792    0.4844    0.9474
    0.8316    0.0259    0.5718    0.0322    0.4067    0.9513    0.9229
    0.3041    0.2078    0.4503    0.4658    0.2488    0.0533    0.8370
>> AAA.set1
ans =
    0.2232    0.9404    0.3981    0.6934    0.5052    0.6516    0.1042
ans =
    0.5832    0.8867    0.2036    0.5595    0.2792    0.4844    0.9474
ans =
    0.8316    0.0259    0.5718    0.0322    0.4067    0.9513    0.9229
ans =
    0.3041    0.2078    0.4503    0.4658    0.2488    0.0533    0.8370

>> mat2
mat2 =
    0.1468    0.8309    0.3492    0.5820    0.1021    0.4695    0.5848
    0.9706    0.2005    0.5406    0.2961    0.3054    0.7118    0.1053
    0.4054    0.6320    0.3319    0.9196    0.8603    0.2329    0.7693
    0.8479    0.5877    0.8974    0.0810    0.8876    0.0734    0.5933
>> AAA.set2
ans =
    0.1468    0.8309    0.3492    0.5820    0.1021    0.4695    0.5848
ans =
    0.9706    0.2005    0.5406    0.2961    0.3054    0.7118    0.1053
ans =
    0.4054    0.6320    0.3319    0.9196    0.8603    0.2329    0.7693
ans =
    0.8479    0.5877    0.8974    0.0810    0.8876    0.0734    0.5933
```

and so on for other matrices.

Comment: I upvoted as it clearly answers the question, but honestly I think that using a loop would be better than this approach.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Agreed on that! Specially dealing with cells could make it slower!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin and Divakar - Agreed on both accounts.  Donald Knuth always said that premature optimization is the root of all evil.  If you can quantifiably measure performance and if you know that doing away with `for` loops will certainly be faster, then do it.  I would certainly go with `for` because it's more readable too.  I do question doing this without loops, especially since we need to convert these to cells.